# Как создать таблицы по коду C# построенному из XSD в Altova XMLSpy

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Я работаю с реестром Fias
мне необходимо получать данные и загружать их в mysql

но это пол беды, сейчас работал в Altova XMLSpy 2022 и по примеру превратил ранее полученные XSD схемы в модель в Altova, после же выгрузил их как код в C#, очень много файлов и не понятно как с ними работать, соответственно гуглил (скорее всего плохо раз не нашел), но в итоге не наткнулся ни на один мануал как этот код на C# из XSD применяли бы в бд

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Таблицы в БД уже есть? Или их нужно создать по схеме?

Comment: Если нужно создать таблицы, то напрашивается подход Code First с ORM Entity Framework.